# How to get rid of if-elif-else clause

Tags: c++

For example, I have some arrays of filenames:

```
char arr[N] = ["FILENAME0", "FILENAME1", "FILENAME2", "FILENAME3", "FILENAME4", ...]
```

How can I write a function which depends on `N` will `fopen` and `fclose` `N` files?
`switch-case` and `if-elif-else` are straightforward, but require a lot of conditions and `N` already should be known (`N` will pass in runtime from stdin).

`For-loop` is not suitable here because it will open and close step by step. I want that at the beginning, function will `fopen` `N` files, then all these `N` files descriptors should be available in memory and only then close `N` files.

I expect that if `N == 1` function will behave like:

```
int func ()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(arr[0]);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

or if `N == 3`:

```
int func ()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(arr[0]);
  FILE *fp1 = fopen(arr[1]);
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(arr[2]);
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two loops, one to open randomly, other to close those opened by the first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Run two functions at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051009/c-run-two-functions-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @narusin quistion is not about multi-threading

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you can use for loop to do this problem. There is nothing difficult about this question.

Comment: Can explain more want you it to do? From what I understand, you want open n number of files then closes judging from your example

Comment: if the order is always the same `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { open(arr[i]); }` and the same for close

Comment: `fopen()` takes 2 arguments.

Comment: two `for` loops will suffice your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your `FILE*`s into a `std::vector` and close them with a second loop:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string>>& filenames) {
    std::vector<FILE*> fds;
    for (const std::string& filename : filenames) {
        fds.push_back(std::fopen(filename.c_str(), "w"));
    }
    // Work with the file descriptors however you want
    for (FILE* fd : fds) {
        std::fclose(fd);
    }
}
```

If you do anything that could throw an exception between when you open the files and when you close them then you may want to use an exception-safe wrapper, rather than closing the `FILE*`s manually:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string>>& filenames) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>> fds;
    for (const std::string& filename : filenames) {
        fds.emplace_back(std::fopen(filename.c_str(), "w"), std::fclose);
    }
    // Work with the file descriptors however you want.  To get
    // the raw FILE* use fds[i].get()

    // std::unique_ptr will call its deleter (std::fclose in this case)
    // on its managed pointer in its destructor, so there's no need to
    // manually close them
}
```

Comment: Got my vote. Probably just a matter of style, but I always find declarations that include `std::vector<someType>` in argument lists/return types as ugly as sin. I _always_ typedef them first, i.e `typedef std::vector<int> vecInt;` and the accompanying iterator,  `typedef vecInt::iterator vecIntIter;`

Comment: Yes, just a matter of style.  I avoid typedefs whenever possible.  I find `std::vector<std::string>` far more expressive than `StringVec`.  Unless the typedef is right next to where it's used, you don't know if a `StringVec` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::vector<const char*>`, `std::vector<QString>`, or what.

Comment: True, I don't - but hovering the type gets your IDE to show you. Thanks for the different perspective to consider. :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a possible solution of shortening `FILE *fp = fopen(arr[0]);` and so on, on `C++`. You are stuck using the `if-elif-else` clause for both opening the file and closing it.

Comment: >then all these `N` files descriptors should be available in memory 
I added to the question.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich would you care to expand on what you want to state? I'm a little confused on what you mean file descriptors should be available in memory.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich Oh I see